# How to get current directory in C# for any Windows version?

Tags: windows, windows-mobile, working-directory

I am creating an application that can be executed in any windows version, even in mobile's, and I am trying to get the current directory of the executable.
The problem is that if I use the following code, it doesn't compile in Windows Mobile:

```
string currentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
```

And if I use this code, I receive something like: ***file:\C:\xxx***

```
string currentDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Although, I need to get the root drive, and this code doesn't compile in Windows Mobile:

```
String rootPath = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
```

Does anyone know how to get the current directory of the application and the root path for any windows version, even mobile's?

Comment: Windows Mobile doesn't have the concept of the current directory. Your app can get the EXE's location from argv[0] in your winMain() function.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines?

```
var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```